# How to add a class to an element if all elements have a given class?

Tags: jquery, each, addclass

I have several div having class `.toCheck`.

By clicking to one of these divs, I'm adding to the clicked div the class `.readyToSend`

I also have a button "#send", and every time I'm clicking a `.toCheck` div, if all the `.toCheck` divs have the class `.readyToSend` I want to add the class ".ready" to "#send".

I was thinking about this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toCheck', function() {
   $(this).addClass(readyToSend);

   var addClassButton = 'yes';

   $('.toCheck').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass('readyToSend')){
         addClassButton = 'no';
      }
   });

   if(addClassButton == 'yes'){
     $('#send').addClass(ready);
   }
});
```

But since JavaScript is asynchronous, I'm afraid that the test:

```
if(addClassButton == 'yes')
```

Will be done before the end of

```
$('.toCheck').each(
```

What should be the best approach to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: None of the code in that event handler is asynchronous, so it will work fine. I would suggest you at least change the `addClassButton` variable to a boolean value though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not **all** JavaScript is asynchronous.

But that can be a lot simpler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toCheck', function() {
   $(this).addClass('readyToSend'); // Quotes here, right?

   $("#send").toggleClass('ready', $(".toCheck:not(.readyToSend)").length ? false : true);
});
```

There, we're adding or remove the class `ready` (I assumed you meant that to be in quotes) based on whether there are any elements with the class `toCheck` that do not have the class `readyToSend`.

The `toggleClass` can also be:

```
   $("#send").toggleClass('ready', !$(".toCheck:not(.readyToSend)").length);
```

...but I thought the conditional above would be clearer to start with.

---

**Live example**:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.toCheck', function() {
   $(this).addClass('readyToSend'); // Quotes here, right?

   $("#send").toggleClass('ready', !$(".toCheck:not(.readyToSend)").length);
});
```

```css
.toCheck {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.readyToSend {
  color: green;
}
.ready {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="toCheck">Click me</div>
<div class="toCheck">Click me</div>
<div class="toCheck">Click me</div>
<div class="toCheck">Click me</div>
<div class="toCheck">Click me</div>
<div id="send">Send</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: toggle class may not be required since we are not removing the class from the items once it is added

Comment: @ArunPJohny: True, but it's convenient. And *usually* for these sorts of things, clicking the `toCheck`s again would un-selected them, though not (as you point out) in the OP's scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple selector `.toCheck:not(.readyToSend)` which will return any `toCheck` element which does not have the `readyToSend` class

```
$(document).on('click', '.toCheck', function () {
    $(this).addClass('readyToSend');

    if ($('.toCheck:not(.readyToSend)').length == 0) {
        $('#send').addClass('ready');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bthxo5h1/)